# ReadAsync get data from buffer

Tags: c#

I've been banging my head around this for some while (and know it's something silly).

I'm downloading files with a ProgressBar which shows fine, but how do I get the data from the `ReadAsync` Stream to save?

```
public static readonly int BufferSize = 4096;
int receivedBytes = 0;
int totalBytes = 0;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
byte[] result;

using (var stream = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(urlToDownload))
{
  byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
  totalBytes = Int32.Parse(client.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.ContentLength]);

  for (;;)
  {
    result = new byte[stream.Length];
    int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (bytesRead == 0)
    {
      await Task.Yield();
      break;
    }

    receivedBytes += bytesRead;
    if (progessReporter != null)
    {
      DownloadBytesProgress args = 
                 new DownloadBytesProgress(urlToDownload, receivedBytes, totalBytes);
      progessReporter.Report(args);
    }
  }
}
```

I was trying via the result var, but that is obviously wrong. I'd appreciate any pointers on this long Sunday afternoon.

Comment: I think you'll need another stream to save the file (buffer) to disk.

Comment: What is the content of your buffer? The content is in your `byte[] buffer` variable

Comment: Well, you are not using `result`. It is impossible that `result` would contain your data because the stream does not even know this variable exists. (I sense that you have some misconception here. Not sure what it is.)

Comment: Yes. It creates a file of correct length with no data in it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The content that was downloaded is inside your `byte[] buffer` variable:

```
int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

From `Stream.ReadAsync`:

> buffer:
>
> Type: System.Byte[]
>   The buffer to write the data into.

You never use your `result` variable at all. Not sure why its there.

**Edit**

So the problem is how to read the full content of your stream. You can do the following:

```
public static readonly int BufferSize = 4096;
int receivedBytes = 0;
WebClient client = new WebClient();

using (var stream = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(urlToDownload))
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    int read = 0;
    totalBytes = Int32.Parse(client.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.ContentLength]);

    while ((read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);

        receivedBytes += read;
        if (progessReporter != null)
        {
           DownloadBytesProgress args = 
             new DownloadBytesProgress(urlToDownload, receivedBytes, totalBytes);

           progessReporter.Report(args);
         }
    }
    return ms.ToArray();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yuzal, but my buffer is limited to 4096 bytes.

Comment: Huh? But that is the buffer you put inside the `ReadAsync` method.

Comment: I was trying to show the percentage complete in small chunks.

Comment: Im confused, you asked where your data is, and you pass your `buffer` variable to `ReadAsync`. Im confused at what you're asking then

Comment: Sorry Yuval, been at this too long probably. I know that the buffer contains the stream data in chunks. I'm just not sure how to append them as it reads.

Comment: Thanks so much, Yuval. That works as it should. Very grateful!

Answer (score 1):

The data you read should be in the `buffer` array. Actually the beginning `bytesRead` bytes of the array.  Check [ReadAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813(v=vs.110).aspx) method on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks Gildor, I think the issue is me limiting buffer size to 4096

Comment: @JohnSourcer Then you should get the first 4096 bytes from the stream. Is that so?

Comment: Yes. But then I need to add the next chunk (until finished) to it surely. In order to get the whole stream.

Comment: @JohnSourcer Yes. Actually what I thought was you should mention that (you already got the initial 4096 bytes) in the question so that people can really help you. Anyway it's good you figured yourself!