# http low level streams

Tags: f#, http-streaming

There's lower level approach to writing and reading stream for web requests, where you read or write as data comes in, please help with a snippet.

```
let request = WebRequest.CreateHttp url
request.Method <- "PUT"
async {
    request.ContentLength <- (int64) schema.Length
    use! requestStream = request.GetRequestStreamAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
    requestStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(schema), 0, schema.Length)
    requestStream.Close()

    use! response = request.AsyncGetResponse()
    use stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    use streamReader = new StreamReader(stream)
    let! data = streamReader.ReadToEndAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
    return Ok(data)
}
```

References used for the above code.

http://www.fssnip.net/7PK/title/Send-async-HTTP-POST-request

Comment: low level approach to reading streams as the data comes in

Comment: Never mind. I got the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ReadToEndAsync`, use `ReadAsync` in a while loop. There are plenty of examples in C# about how to use these api's here is a simple one: [ReadAsync get data from buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105089/readasync-get-data-from-buffer)

Also there are Async based stream apis in `FSharp.Core` here a code sample: http://www.fssnip.net/nP/title/Async-demo